# Git Extension is working slow on local commit and merge

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have Git Extensions 2.32 installed and i encounter a strange issue. When i commit and merge locally it take approximative 1 minute to do the changes, but when i push and merge on remote it takes 3-6 seconds. Do you have any ideas why this it takes longer locally?